# Date Field data types varchar are incompatible with subtract operator in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've tried to search the answer for this but none of the solutions I've found have worked.

I need to subtract 2 date fields from one other: datearrival - date departed but these are both varchar and so the subtract operator won't work.

Can someone give me an answer in code, perhaps using cast and/or date diff to make this work?

my current code is:

```
DATEDIFF(dd,[ARRIVDAT],current_timestamp)-(dd,[DEPARTDAT],currenttimestamp) AS LengthOfStay
```

This is highlighting the column names as not being recognised, even though in the rest of the query the multi-bound identifiers are fine.

Any good answers please?

Comment: Fix your schema and don't store dates as strings. Use `date` or `datetime` or similar types. That said, have you tried something like `convert(date, arrivdat)`?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: `(dd,[DEPARTDAT],currenttimestamp)` doesn't make any sense by itself. Was that meant to be a *function call* of some kind? (E.g. another `DATEPART` call) If so, you've forgotten to give the function name.

Comment: @sticky bit thanks, you provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ARRIVDAT varchar(12) ='1JAN18', @DEPARTDAT varchar(12) = '2FEB18'
select DATEDIFF(dd, @ARRIVDAT, @DEPARTDAT) LengthOfStay
```

I think it'll do an implicit conversion. You don't need cast or convert also.

Answer (score 0):

You want the function `DATEDIFF()`.  You can convert the values:

```
DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, ARRIVDAT]), CONVERT(date, DEPARTDAT) AS LengthOfStay
```

If the implicit conversion doesn't work, then peruse the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the appropriate format that does work.